# I am trying to optimize this mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am getting above 12s for this silly query

```
SELECT *
FROM notifications
WHERE `to` IN (SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower = 3)
LIMIT 0,20
```

Any idea what the problem could be? Should I use a join?

Comment: Try the `join` version and see if it runs faster.  Yes, you should do that.

Comment: Try using join and replace * with column names. You can remove some columns if You don't need them.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `to` and/or `follower` fields?

Comment: To is a mysql reserved keyword you should normally get an error. May be internally mysql is handling it and it takes long ?

Comment: @PoX: It's in backticks, so that's not a problem.  If it wasn't, the query wouldn't even run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the following "covering", multi-column index:

```
followers(follower, following)
```

MySQL will be able to run the uncorrelated subquery just once, but it will likely scan through all rows in the notifications table, comparing the result against it. If you have many rows in notifications, this query could be slow.

Using a `JOIN` in the following format, MySQL is able to immediately reduce the result set down to just those rows in the followers table where follower is 3:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM followers f
JOIN notifications n
  ON n.`to` = f.following
WHERE f.follower = 3
```

MySQL will then do a look up into the notifications table for each record where the 'to' column matches. Depending on your dataset, this may be faster than a full table scan on notifications.

For the `JOIN`, you will also want to add the following index:

```
notifications(`to`)
```

If you can narrow the results to just a few named columns, then add those named columns to the index as well to create a covering, multi-column index:

```
SELECT n.name, n.notification
FROM followers f
JOIN notifications n
  ON n.`to` = f.following
WHERE f.follower = 3
```

Then a covering index like this:

```
notifications(`to`, name, notification)
```